# Bootcamp and Windows Recovery Partition

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition, recovery

Currently I am running Windows 10 on my MBP with bootcamp. In OS X, in disk utility, there is an "Untitled" partition of ~ 450MB. Upon closer inspection using disk management in Windows and the "diskutil list" command in OS X, this appears to be the windows recovery partition that windows 10 has made.

Is it safe to delete this partition, with the "diskpart" command within windows, without harming my partition tables/making my operating systems unbootable, etc.?

Comment: Don't touch the drive from Windows, it doesn't understand how it's fooled into thinking it's in charge. Safest would be leave it alone for the sake of 'half a CD' of space.

Comment: If so, do you have any idea how I should go about deleting that partition?

Comment: Can you please post your answer as an answer not a comment, so I can mark it as solved? Thanks, I think I'll leave the partition there and delete it from OS X if I decide to delete Windows